# Check if an url is blocked by robots.txt using Perl

Tags: perl

Can anybody tell me sample code to check if an url has been blocked by robots.txt?
We can specify full url or directory in the robots.txt.
Is there any helper function in Perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out `WWW::RobotRules`:

```
   The following methods are provided:

   $rules = WWW::RobotRules->new($robot_name)
  This is the constructor for WWW::RobotRules objects.  The first
  argument given to new() is the name of the robot.

   $rules->parse($robot_txt_url, $content, $fresh_until)
  The parse() method takes as arguments the URL that was used to
  retrieve the /robots.txt file, and the contents of the file.

   $rules->allowed($uri)
  Returns TRUE if this robot is allowed to retrieve this URL.
```

Comment: In $robot_name can I specify browser name? Because some servers reject requests from Bots. Can I use this: "Mozilla/4.76 [en] (Win98; U)" ?

Comment: @AgA, a site that blocks all robots should also have a `robots.txt` that blocks all robots.  If you're going to respect `robots.txt`, there's no point in lying about your agent name.

Comment: Can I reuse same $rules for different websites?

Answer (score 3):

[WWW::RobotRules](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aRobotRules) is the standard class for parsing robots.txt files and then checking URLs to see if they're blocked.

You may also be interested in [LWP::RobotUA](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aRobotUA), which integrates that into [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent), automatically fetching and checking robots.txt files as needed.

Comment: How can I replace this call with RobotUA?: my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new(env_proxy => 1,keep_alive => 1, timeout => 30, agent => "Mozilla/4.76 [en] (Win98; U)");

Answer (score 1):

Load the robots.txt file and search for "Disallow:" in the file. Then check if the following pattern (after the Disallow:) is within your URL. If so, the URL is banned by the robots.txt

Example - 
You find the following line in the robots.txt:

> Disallow: /cgi-bin/

Now remove the "Disallow: " and check, if "/cgi-bin/" (the remaining part) is directly after the TLD.

If your URL looks like:

> www.stackoverflow.com/cgi-bin/somwhatelse.pl

it is banned.

If your URL looks like:

> www.stackoverflow.com/somwhatelse.pl

it is ok. The complete set of rules you'll find on http://www.robotstxt.org/. This is the way, if you can not install additional modules for any reason.

Better would be to use a module from cpan:
There is a great module on cpan that I use to deal with it: [LWP::RobotUA](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.02/lib/LWP/RobotUA.pm). LWP (libwww) is imho the standard for webaccess in perl - and this module is part of it and ensures your behaviour is nice.

Comment: Will this take care of all possibilities? I mean in all ways an url exclusion can be specified in robots. I'm not sure. Isn't any library function available?

Comment: That's why I recommend to use LWP::RobotUA

Answer (score 0):

Hum, you don't seem to have even looked! On the first page of [search results](http://search.cpan.org/search?q=robots), I see various download engines that handle robots.txt automatically for you, and at least one that does exactly what you asked.

Comment: I've searched in Google, no useful top results. Same in stackoverflow. I'm not a pro like you.

Comment: @AgA, CPAN is where one searches for Perl modules.

Answer (score 0):

WWW::RobotRules skips rules "*substring*"

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: *anytext*
```

url http://example.com/some_anytext.html be passed (not banned)